# Generic features in iPhone peer to peer App, ideas needed

Tags: iphone, generics, frameworks, p2p, ios-frameworks

My student project is to develop a Generic Framework for peer-to-peer system on handhold devices.(iPod)

There is already an existing framework(Gamekit) that build the network and send messages, I'm working on top of it and trying to develop some generic features for common p2p applications.

Any idea what function would be **Generic** here?

Answer (score 1):

You will need some minimum functionalities such as:

- linking a given device with an IP address
- finding the ip adress of a given device on the net
- Eventually techniques to perform NAT traversal
- establish a couple of central peers to bootstrap your network
- request/echange electronic resources between remote devices

Of course, you will need to design some standard messages between peers to perform those transactions

Comment: Thanks a lot, JVerstry.    There is an existing framework (Gamekit) that establish p2p network and transfer messages use socket and streams.  Only using existing API is far not enough for a research project, I should develop some generic features to support common p2p applications. Any more ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Jing P2P is often used for the following: file sharing, phone conversations (a la skype), distributed computing (problems requiring many computers to work in parallel), chat, games...